# How to add dependencies and make it visible to Intero in Haskell

Tags: haskell, intero

I want to use `System.Directory` in emacs with Haskell mode and Intero, While the on the fly check warns that `Couldn't find module System.Directory`. So I add some dependencies in my cabal file. And the warning doesn't disappear while the `stack build` successfully executed.

Below is my cabal file:

```
-- This file has been generated from package.yaml by hpack version 0.28.2.
--
-- see: https://github.com/sol/hpack
--
-- hash: 536b5f6ecaaec7d4b7a9694c8f69bbe648a1d21d80fa721e533ac5b139955401

name:           find
version:        0.1.0.0
description:    Please see the README on GitHub at <https://github.com/Handora/find#readme>
homepage:       https://github.com/Handora/find#readme
bug-reports:    https://github.com/Handora/find/issues
author:         Handora
maintainer:     qcdsr970209@gmail.com
copyright:      Qian Chen
license:        BSD3
license-file:   LICENSE
build-type:     Simple
cabal-version:  >= 1.10
extra-source-files:
    ChangeLog.md
    README.md

source-repository head
  type: git
  location: https://github.com/Handora/find

library
  exposed-modules:
      Lib
      RecursiveContents
  other-modules:
      Paths_find
  hs-source-dirs:
      src
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , directory
  default-language: Haskell2010

executable find-exe
  main-is: Main.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_find
  hs-source-dirs:
      app
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , find
    , directory
  default-language: Haskell2010

test-suite find-test
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Spec.hs
  other-modules:
      Paths_find
  hs-source-dirs:
      test
  ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:
      base >=4.7 && <5
    , find
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

I add the `directory` into build dependencies and executable build dependencies. So my question is how to make the `System.Directory` visible to `Intero`, so the warnings can disappear.

Comment: I don't know if this is the "right way" to do it but i just run `intero-restart`

Comment: It completely solves my problem, thanks.

Comment: @NeilLocketz This should be an answer.

Comment: If you're running spacemacs, `intero-restart` is bound to `<spc> m i r`.

Comment: @Shersh, Done :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it to show up by running `intero-restart`.

There may be a "more correct" way, but this works.